# Ошибка при установке Django в виртуальной среде

Tags: python, django, unicode, virtualenv

Хотел установить Django в виртуальную среду, совершил последовательность действий:

1. `virtualenv --no-site-packages djangokurs`
2. `cd djangokurs/`
3. `source bin/activate`
4. `easy_install django`

После чего вылетела ошибка ([скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdQJK.jpg)):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nicl/Документы/Python/kurs/djangokurs/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "/home/nicl/Документы/Python/kurs/djangokurs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2291, in main
  **kw
File "/home/nicl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "/home/nicl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "/home/nicl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "/home/nicl/Документы/Python/kurs/djangokurs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 409, in run
  self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
[...]
File "/home/nicl/Документы/Python/kurs/djangokurs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 800, in install_script
  self.write_script(script_name, _to_ascii(script_text), 'b')
File "/home/nicl/Документы/Python/kurs/djangokurs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 105, in _to_ascii
  return s.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 13-21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось слишком просто. Русское название папки "Документы" помешало

Comment: Строго говоря, это не решение проблемы, а её избегание

Comment: @andreymal оно действительно так не работает. На python2 валится при попытке создать virtualenv, на python3 при установке пакетов. Мне кажется тут больше косяк в районе pip/easy_install. По хорошему надо бы баг зарепортить